# Apply Curve to an existing Animation

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Project

Hi, I'm learning how to use [`AnimatedList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) in Flutter. I was able to add and remove elements to the list with a [`SizeTransition`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizeTransition-class.html):

#### Code

```dart
Widget _buildItem(
    BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
  return SizeTransition(
    sizeFactor: animation,
    axis: Axis.vertical,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(displayList[index].toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now, I cannot understand how I can add a custom curve to this transition. Is this possibile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question!

As the example in the documentation mentions, you can make use of a [`CurvedAnimation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/CurvedAnimation-class.html):

```dart
CurvedAnimation(
  parent: animation,
  curve: Curves.ease,
  reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut,
),
```

The `reverseCurve` parameter is *optional*. The curved animation will just use the `curve` in both directions if no reverse curve is supplied.
Applied to your code:

```dart
return SizeTransition(
  sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
    parent: animation,
    curve: Curves.ease,
  ),
  ...
)
```